# Can't push refs to remote

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-push, git-pull

First this error shows , then in output terminal it says

```
Failed to execute git {

  "exitCode": 1,

  "gitErrorCode": "PushRejected",

  "gitCommand": "push",

  "stdout": "",

  "stderr": "To https://github.com/deepansh-divik/E-Commerce-Website\n ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)\nerror: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/deepansh-divik/E-Commerce-Website'\nhint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind\nhint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.\nhint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.\nhint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.\n"

}
```

I have been trying to push but nothing works.
It says pull to integrate but when i try to pull rebase
It says : There is no tracking information for the current branch.

Help me solve this , i am a begginer with git and i am doing this with vscode.

I tried to push my files to a repository but it says that its not integrated and i have to pull to integrate and when i fo that it says there is no tracking information.
I also tried to publish main to github but it got rejected and the error with i described in the beginning. I am using vs code , can someone give me a very straight approach to solve this problem i am a newbie with git

Comment: You can't pull unless your branch has a set upstream. Either 1) set the upstream for your branch to be the remote branch and then `git pull`, or 2) `git fetch` and `git merge origin/main` (assuming your called the remote `origin`)

Answer (score 1):

For the first error: Most likely, your local branch is pointing to a remote branch that has been updated. Meaning, someone else may have pushed their changes to that same branch. As a result, git is telling you that you need to merge those changes into your branch before pushing to the remote, which would be initiated by calling "git pull". However, you are apparently having trouble doing this because of a second issue.

The second issue: When calling git pull, git is telling you that you don't have tracking information. This usually means that the branch you are on is not linked to the remote branch. To fix this, you could use:

```
git branch --set-upstream <remote repo name> <branch name>
```

then call git pull again.

You didn't post your commands, so this is based on a lot of speculation. For example, the above would be the case if you don't have your local linked to the remote and you made the following calls (assuming branch named mybranch and remote called origin):

```
git push origin mybranch
(failed)
git pull
(failed)
```

Sometimes you can also temporarily get around this by specifying the remote in the pull:

```
git pull origin mybranch
```

I don't recall if there is a way to do exactly this in vscode (the gui part). I find the git feature in vs code a little lacking myself, so if I had to do this I would use the terminal built into vscode and just do it myself.